# Simple C# log file

Tags: c#, logging

I have a program, and I want it to log stuff into a .txt file with this technique:

```
if (Directory.Exists(@"C:\Log"))
        {
            string[] start = { DateTime.Now + ": Program Started\n" };
            File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Log\Log.txt", start);
            Console.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Log");
            string[] start = { DateTime.Now + ": Program Started\n" };
            File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Log\Log.txt", start);
            Console.Clear();
        }
```

With this technique I have a problem. When I check the log file after the program runs, I only find one line instead of a few more, because this is only just the program startup. So it should look like this:

(time): Program started 
(time): Some stuff happened 
(time): Program closed

instead of:

(time): Program closed

Answer (score 5):

Your program should be like this :

```
if (!Directory.Exists(@"C:\Log")) {
    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Log");
}

...

// Your program runs, you add log lines
string[] start = { DateTime.Now + ": Program Started\n" };
File.AppendAllLines(@"C:\Log\Log.txt", start);
// End add log lines

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use StreamWriter :

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Log.txt", true))
{
  sw.WriteLine("Hello Log");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers, the File.AppendAllLines works!

Answer (score 1):

I run some like this

```
if (!Directory.Exists(path))
 {
    DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
 }

File.AppendAllText(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, path, folderTarget, fileTarget), "Hello Log");
```

Answer (score 0):

`File.WriteAllLines` will overwrite your file each time you call it. You want to append your text to a file. You could use `File.AppendAllLines` or `File.AppendAllText` since it looks like you only have one line to write at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are using [`File.WriteAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines(v=vs.110).aspx), which creates a new file each time when called, to fix this problem you you could use [`File.AppendAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383691(v=vs.110).aspx) which *Appends* lines to a file, and then closes the file. If the specified file does not exist, `File.AppendAllLines` method creates a file.